# Angular2: highcharts-angular chart doesn't render

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, render

I used the **highcharts-angular** wrapper to use **highcharts** in an angular component.

My template is:

```
 <highcharts-chart>
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="my-chart"
  style = "width: 100%; height: 500px; display: block;"
</highcharts-chart>
```

But somehow it doesn't show at all.
In the corresponding .ts file:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'
```

imports highcharts (which I of course added via npm),
and my chart in .ts file looks like

```
my-chart = {
   chart: {
     ...
   }
}
```

with ... being a correct highcharts chart.

In app.module, I added *HighchartsChartComponent* from **highcharts-angular**.

I'm convinced I did everything right.
But somehow, my chart doesn't show it all, according to dev console it seems to be 1x1 pixel in the angular component  :(

Comment: What is the container of `highcharts-chart` component? Is it a component? Then you have to add `display: block` property in your component.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you for answering. How exactly do you mean to add this property in the component? HighchartsChartComponent is built-in from this library and I guess the property is already there?

Comment: Add `:host {display: block;}` to your css file.

Comment: Already did this as my-chart {display: block;}   Now tried with host: but it still won't show

Comment: I found [angular-highchart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts) a better option

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

- In your **app.module.ts** you should have `import { HighchartsChartModule } from "highcharts-angular";` instead of `HighchartsChartComponent`.
- This name is not correct: `my-chart` and probably cause the issue. You should change it and use these ones: `myChart` or `my_chart`

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/54lyn5rvyp

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the highchart tag too soon.
And your options variable is wrong as Wojciech mentioned.
This

```
 <highcharts-chart>
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="my-chart"
  style = "width: 100%; height: 500px; display: block;"
</highcharts-chart>
```

needs to be

```
<highcharts-chart
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="myChart"
  style = "width: 100%; height: 500px; display: block;">    
</highcharts-chart>
```